# Typescript compile issues when using ESM

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules

I have a larger Typescript UI project with numerous issues where I would appreciate some help:

1. Property 'xyz' does not exist on type

   ```bash
   src/index.ts:6:13 - error TS2339: Property 'click' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/111122223333/Projects/ts-issue/node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/types/index")'.

   6   userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('textbox'))
   ```
2. This expression is not callable

   ```bash
   src/index.ts:9:15 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
   Type 'typeof import("/Users/111122223333/Projects/ts-issue/node_modules/next/index")' has no call signatures.

   9   const app = next({
   ```
3. JSX element type 'xyz' does not have any construct or call signatures

   ```bash
   src/pages/test.tsx:6:8 - error TS2604: JSX element type 'Head' does not have any construct or call signatures.

   6       <Head>

   src/pages/test.tsx:6:8 - error TS2786: 'Head' cannot be used as a JSX component.
     Its type 'typeof import("/Users/111122223333/Projects/ts-issue/node_modules/next/head")' is not a valid JSX element type.

   6       <Head>
   ```

They seem to be related and I was able to isolate them in a sample [repository](https://github.com/katjes733/ts-issue). Full disclaimer: The code does not necessarily make sense, but shall serve as example only.

The errors get reported when running `tsc --noEmit` (here using `npm run ts:check`)

The [README.md](https://github.com/katjes733/ts-issue/blob/19379087936a84399ed709177a0933a0103582da/README.md) has additional details, but my problem boils down to why adding `default` to the offending lines of code resolves the issues, as IMHO I should not have to do that.

I expect the code to compile successfully without having to add `default`. I played with some combinations of compiler settings, but they would not change the outcome and in fact introduce other issues.

I do suspect some sort on configuration problem, but cannot seem to figure it out.

Any insights and background information would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You have dynamic `import`s which return Promises, which cannot be called as functions, do not take click handlers, etc. You need to either use static imports or `await` the Promises from the dynamic imports. This has nothing to do with Typescript, other than Typescript (correctly) telling you your code doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @JaredSmith: unless i am blind, I never use dynamic imports in my code. All my imports are at the top of my files and i thought those are considered static imports. If i misunderstood what you wrote, I would appreciate if you could clarify for me, please.

Comment: I was gleaning that from the error message where it says `import('...`. Your code in your repository *appears* to be using static imports, but it also appears incomplete: the code in your question doesn't seem to be in `main`, and I don't see any other branches.

Comment: @JaredSmith: 
Issue 1: [link](https://github.com/katjes733/ts-issue/blob/14444bd5b3b8d8c15b07cf645f2129e8093024bc/src/index.ts#L13)

Issue 2: [link](https://github.com/katjes733/ts-issue/blob/14444bd5b3b8d8c15b07cf645f2129e8093024bc/src/index.ts#L16)
Issue 3: [link](https://github.com/katjes733/ts-issue/blob/14444bd5b3b8d8c15b07cf645f2129e8093024bc/src/pages/test.tsx#L6)
All the code is in the main branch

Answer (score 0):

Remove `"type": "module"` from **package.json** and `await` from line *24* in **src/index.ts**. Sorry for not being able to provide with any further insights.

> I have already sent a [PR](https://github.com/katjes733/ts-issue/pull/1) with the fix.

Comment: Removing `"type": "module"` effectively treats everything as CommonJS. The idea was to move everything to the newer ES Modules.
While The suggestion works, would it not be recommended to move forward with ES Modules? What would I have to change to make my code work then?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't support CommonJS anyway. So adding the declaration is irrelevant and may cause potential code breakage (as you've already seen).